# rosbridge example, no output

Tags: ros, tutorial, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Installed rosbridge_suite for indigo distro. Testing [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/keyboardteleopjs/Tutorials/CreatingABasicTeleopWidgetWithSpeedControl) in rosbridge tutorials by changing the following for my robot:

```
28. topic: '/Pioneer3AT/rqt/cmd_vel
```

I run the following:

```
roslaunch pioneer3at power_pioneer.launch
```

To launch the robot.

Then run the following:

```
roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch
```

To create websocket. That connects fine. I start the HTML page in Chrome. The slider loads, the topic /Pioneer3AT/rqt/cmd_vel does not publish. Do I need to edit more of the HTML in order to run with my robot? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201641/rosbridge-example,-no-output/) by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2015-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Be sure to change the IP/URL in line 22 to your computer (or localhost most likely).

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2015-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2015-01-24**:
Works beautifully.